# Timer not starting?

Tags: java, swing, timer

I keep getting a  expected error at the displayTimer.start(); line... what's the reason for this? I am just trying to understand how to use the swing Timer with two inputs into the constructor, and nothing else fancier. I got this code from: http://albertattard.blogspot.com/2008/09/practical-example-of-swing-timer.html

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Five {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    System.out.println("hello");
                }
            };
        Timer displayTimer = new Timer(1000, listener);
        displayTimer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Place your code in a method

Comment: Woops. Okay, adding the main method that fixed that error, but now it doesn't seem to be constantly running... it never prints hello.

Comment: It is listening for an action which never comes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> adding the main method that fixed that error, but now it doesn't seem to be constantly running... it never prints hello.

Probably because the JVM exists before the Timer has a chance to fire. The point of a Timer is to use it with a GUI.

So create a more practical example.  First create a JFrame and make the frame visible. Then the JVM will not exit while the frame is visible. Then you can start the Timer.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information on the different Threads used in Swing.

Comment: I added JFrame f = new JFrame(); f.setVisible(true) and that did the trick!